# Overriding onOverScrolled in NestedScrollView results in incorrect values

Tags: android, overscroll, nestedscrollview

I'm trying to achieve an 'overscroll' to trigger an action effect in my NestedScrollView (which is together with a CollapsingToolbarLayout in a Coordinator Layout). I've created my own View by extending NestedScrollView and overriding onOverScrolled:

```
    protected void onOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX, boolean clampedY) { }
```

However, I'm not getting any useful values. When the NestedScrollView contains content with a height of less than a full 'screen' (including the Collapsing Toolbar) the value is always 0. When the content is more than a full 'screen', the method is triggered while simply scrolling through the content without overscrolling.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Are there any other ways to trigger an overscroll action in a NestedScrollView?